# Battery comparison on 2G vs 3G

Tags: settings, lumia

Nokia lumia 710 is great windows device but with a mediocre 1320 mAh battery. The phone needs a charge twice a day with moderate to heavy usage. Right now I am using a 3G internet pack on mobile which is two and half times expensive than 2G.

My question is how the battery will perform on 2G? Will it be same like 3G, or some improvement in battery life

Comment: your post may meet a similar fate to this one http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/868/which-uses-more-battery-power-wifi-or-4g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite hard to answer your question, because it really depends how you use your phone.

However it is little bit easier when we talk about stand-by. It's quite typical that the battery lasts longer on 3G, but only if you have strong signal. When you have on like 1-2 bars, phone might start switching between networks and that will greatly affect your battery life.

Comment: Ya that was what I wondering. When the highest connection speed is set to 3g, the phone keeps jumping between **H** , **3G** & **E**.

Comment: It also depends on where you are located - my 3G coverage is average, but even if it were excellent, the cost of keeping my phone solely on the 3G connection would be insane, so E does the job quite nicely for browsing the web, emails, Whatsapp, and the battery life is good enough.